# Add padding-left css property to clarity tabs labels

Tags: css, angular, padding, vmware-clarity

I have 2 clarity tabs in the project (StackBlitz ref is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-zoxzfo?file=app/app.component.html)).

[image]

And I would like to add `padding-left` property to Tab1 (the tab label itself, not the content) so there will be some space.
Using Chrome Dev Tools I found the needed selector . It's `ul.nav` element inside `clr-tabs`.

But if I add a css property in `app.component.css` like this

```
ul.nav {
  padding-left: 1rem !important;
}
```

nothing really changes. So how can I add `padding` property to those tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a CSS class:

```
button.tab-button{
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Then, give that class to the each button on HTML:

```
<button clrTabLink id="inputs-link" class="tab-button">Tab1</button>
```

and

```
<button clrTabLink id="filters-link" class="tab-button">Tab2</button>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I need to add the class to the first button and add `padding-left` property to it.